# OpenLayers get coordinates of touch points?

Tags: javascript, touch, coordinates, openlayers

I am registering the "click" event on the map to get the Lon and Lat of the mouse click like this:

```
map.events.register("click", map, function(e) {
   var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);
});
```

This works fine on my PC(click), but doesn't get triggered on my Android tablet(touch). So it gets triggered on click, but not on touch. I have to register the event to my layer to get it to trigger on touch(https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/20859) like this:

```
layer.events.register("touchstart", layer, function(e) {
 //e.xy is undefined
});
```

This gets triggered, but for some reason event.xy is undefined?

How do I get the touch coordinates when using touch on a tablet?

Answer (score 0):

It's not so easy to get the coordinates from the touchstart event.
Touchstart event comes with a touches array, each one containing some coordinates, but using different properties.
OpenLayers normalizes the touchstart event in the OpenLayers.Event class method getTouchClientXY.

Also, I can't find any click/touchstart event in the layer class. Maybe you are using some other subclass or a custom one...

However, depending on your needs, you could

1. create a drawfeature control, with a point handler and listen to the featureadded event
2. define a custom control that use the OpenLayers.Handler.Click (that handles click/touchstart correctly)
3. if you need to select a vector feature, use the SelectFeature control
4. Handle the "touchstart" event using a for loop to find xy coordinates in the touches property

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me. This also triggers click event with touch:

```
OpenLayers.Control.Click = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {                
            defaultHandlerOptions: {
                'single': true,
                'double': false,
                'pixelTolerance': 0,
                'stopSingle': false,
                'stopDouble': false
            },

            initialize: function(options) {
                this.handlerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.extend(
                    {}, this.defaultHandlerOptions
                );
                OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(
                    this, arguments
                ); 
                this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Click(
                    this, {
                        'click': this.trigger
                    }, this.handlerOptions
                );
            }, 

            trigger: function(e) {
                var coordinates = map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy);
            }

        });

 var click = new OpenLayers.Control.Click();
                map.addControl(click);
                click.activate();
```

Answer (score 0):

i use 
    e.clientX
instead of
    e.x 
or the touch. 
Have a look in my code if you want In taphold.js
        [http://ozonforages.free.fr/mobile.html]